# Can Azure Service Bus topics be used as an event source or is there a better hosted service on Azure for this?

Tags: event-sourcing, azure-servicebus-topics

Can Azure Service Bus topics be used for event-sourcing?

At first sight it seem to be a good fit, but have anybody tried it? Can anybody confirm that keeping events forever in the Azure Service Bus topic is working well?

Or is there a better hosted service on Azure for this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean in the sense of [Event Sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html)?

Wouldn't recommend it. Service Bus has a maximum queue/topic size and is designed to be dequeued. Arguably you could design your replay logic as a dequeue-all and re-queue to retain the application state, but this is definitely not the intention of the product.

It also as far as I am aware has no notion of geographic replication, although the storage behind service bus itself is resilient within the data centre. For maximum redundancy I'd choose a storage technology that supports replication away from the primary data centre.

Comment: Yes, exactly, for event sourcing. I want a persistent storage of all business events with unlimited storage time and capacity. And I want a simple service on Azure. What options do I have? I'll edit the question.

Comment: [Azure Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-about)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also interested in that topic and from the outside it looks like [Azure Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-about) is the right service for that.